# How to download asset file to local storage from Firebase and after that open it from local storage?

Tags: firebase, flutter, pdf, assets

I want to download a PDF from Firebase to local storage in my app. When the download is complete, I want to open that PDF file in my app from local storage.

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#downloading-files?

Answer (score 1):

first you can download a file in your Firebase like this

```
await FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref(yourFirebaseFile)
        .writeToFile(localFileLocation).then((data){  
       //open the pdf file here
    });
```

and to open your local pdf now you can use a package like this:

https://pub.dev/packages/advance_pdf_viewer